# SqlDataReader Can't Proceed into While

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem in `SqlDataReader` - it cannot proceed into while and cannot while.

Here is my code

```
List<tmp_WatchList> data = new List<tmp_WatchList>();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckPersonList", con)) 
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;

            SqlDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                //data.Add(new tmp_WatchList
                //{
                tmp_WatchList l = new tmp_WatchList();
                l.id = int.Parse(oReader["id"].ToString());
                l.Name = oReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                l.Crime = int.Parse(oReader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                data.Add(l);
                ///});
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and my stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CheckPersonList]
    (@Name NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT REPLACE(Name, '.', ''), Crime
    FROM [dbo].[tmp_WatchList]
    WHERE [Name] LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(@Name, ' ', '%'), '%')
END
```

Can you tell me how it is done? Or is something wrong with my structure?

Comment: Open connection, and  even thou it's obvious here, next time please post the error message

Comment: Well, my mistake for not putting the con.Open(); sorry for that.. its my practice to try and test every aspect of possible solution.. my problem is that when try to debug can't read the data inside into while and it shows this error : **webengine4.pdb not Loaded**

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) ... throw new Exception(ex.Message);` this doesn't achieve anything good. And `SqlDataReader` implements `IDisposable` so it should be wrapped in a `using` statement.

Comment: @MaxFord then edit the question so that we can undestand batter

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

You are not opening the connection  any where before calling the `ExecuteReader`, you need to open the database connection, following  is the lineo of code to open the connection  :

```
con.Open(); // open connection
SqlDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // now execute SP
```

and you do not need finally block for closing the connection, as you are already applyuing the `using` block on your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` which is converted by compiler in to `try` `finally` which takes care  of disposing  the resources and in case of  `SqlConnection` closing the connection.

Comment: Also note that the `finally` block is not needed - the `using` block will take care of closing the connection when the block is exited, even if an error is thrown.

Comment: My mistake.. Thanks.. and the other problem is that when i try to debug the code.. it shows me the Error Debugging: **webengine4.pdb not Loaded**.. 
already tried to search but no luck.

Comment: @Tim you are right, added that, MaxFord  try cleaning  and rebuilding  your  solutio

Comment: found out the cause of error. it was on my proc.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out, you need to `Open` the connection, and you can simplify your code removing the `try/catch/finally` and the explicit `con.Close()`, which you don't need since you are (corretcly) wrapping the connection within a `using`

Your code should be something like this (much cleaner than the original one after removing the try/catch/finally):

```
List<tmp_WatchList> data = new List<tmp_WatchList>();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CheckPersonList", con)) 
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;

        SqlDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (oReader.Read())
        {
            tmp_WatchList l = new tmp_WatchList();
            l.id = int.Parse(oReader["id"].ToString());
            l.Name = oReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            l.Crime = int.Parse(oReader.GetValue(2).ToString());
            data.Add(l);
        }
    }
}
```

If that code raises an exception, it will simply be forwarded to the caller, in a better way comparing to what you did with your `throw new Exception(exc.Message)`, which will loose the original stack trace

Comment: Thanks.. i think the problem is on my procedure side.. don't know why.. Thanks btw..

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the unwanted code..Try Like this..



 List<tmp_WatchList> data = new List<tmp_WatchList>();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommmandText="sp_CheckPersonList";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    con.Open();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",name);
    SqlDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                tmp_WatchList l = new tmp_WatchList();
                l.id = int.Parse(oReader["id"].ToString());
                l.Name = oReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                l.Crime = int.Parse(oReader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                data.Add(l);
            }

    oReader.Close();
    Con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks.. i think the problem is on my procedure side.. don't know why.. Thanks btw..